# Adding in minutes between rows in SQL Server 2008 - Updated

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Re-writing and Re-posting this question as the previous question was a mess. My Apologies.

I am attempting to create a report that shows how long specific events are lasting, specifically the time between events. An example of the data I am working with is :

```
> LoggedOnUser|EventDate |EventTime|EventID 
> DWH         |08/10/2015|07:45:00 |4624
> DWH         |08/10/2015|07:46:00 |4800 
> DWH         |08/10/2015|07:50:00 |4801
> DWH         |08/10/2015|08:27:00 |4800 
> DWH         |08/10/2015|16:18:00 |4801
> DWH         |08/10/2015|16:31:00 |4647
```

The data is simple and the query used to select the above is

```
SELECT sd.LoggedOnUser
          , sd.EventDate
          , CAST(dateadd(mi, datediff(mi, 0, sd.EventTime), 0)
            AS TIME(7)) AS EventTime
          , sd.EventID
 FROM dbo.tblStaffLoggedInDetails AS sd
     WHERE LoggedOnUser = 'DWH'
     AND EventDate = '08-Oct-2015'
```

I have an Interval table that has all the 1 minute intervals. The desired output is going to be :

```
> LoggedOnUser|EventDate |EventTime|EventID 
> DWH         |08/10/2015|07:45:00 |4624
> DWH         |08/10/2015|07:46:00 |4800 
> DWH         |08/10/2015|07:47:00 |4800
> DWH         |08/10/2015|07:48:00 |4800
> DWH         |08/10/2015|07:49:00 |4800
> DWH         |08/10/2015|07:50:00 |4801
> DWH         |08/10/2015|07:51:00 |4801
> DWH         |08/10/2015|07:52:00 |4801
> DWH         |08/10/2015|07:53:00 |4801
> DWH         |08/10/2015|07:54:00 |4801
```

and so on...

I have so far got to this point

```
SELECT ii.IntervalHHMM
        , dd.LoggedOnUser
        , dd.EventDate
        , dd.EventTime
        , dd.EventID
FROM  (SELECT IntervalHHMM
                FROM dtLookups.dbo.tblIntervalHHMM AS i) AS ii LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT LoggedOnUser
                , EventDate
                , CAST(DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, 0, EventTime), 0)
                  AS TIME(7)) AS EventTime
                , EventID
                , Action
    FROM dbo.tblStaffLoggedInDetails AS sd
        WHERE (LoggedOnUser = 'DWH') AND (EventDate = '08-Oct-2015')) 
    AS dd 
    ON ii.IntervalHHMM = dd.EventTime
GROUP BY dd.LoggedOnUser, dd.EventDate,
         dd.EventTime, dd.EventID,
         dd.Action, ii.IntervalHHMM
ORDER BY ii.IntervalHHMM
```

Which works to a degree but has a lot of NULLS. See the image below for what I currently return and what ideally I need.

[image: Current Result(left) and Desired (Right)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case is that you do `LEFT JOIN`:

```
╔══════════════╗╔═══════════╦══════════════╗   
║ IntervalHHMM ║║ EventTime ║ LoggedOnUser ║
╠══════════════╣╠═══════════╬══════════════╣
║ 08:52:00     ║║ 08:52:00  ║ DWH          ║
║ 08:53:00     ║║ 08:53:00  ║ DWH          ║
║ 08:55:00     ║║ 08:55:00  ║ DWH          ║
║ 08:56:00     ║║           ║              ║
║ 08:57:00     ║║           ║              ║
║ 08:58:00     ║║           ║              ║
║ 08:59:00     ║║           ║              ║
║ 09:00:00     ║║ 09:00:00  ║ DWH          ║
║ 09:01:00     ║║           ║              ║
╚══════════════╝╚═══════════╩══════════════╝
```

Now the result you get is perfectly fine, but you want to replicate `LoggedOnUser` and `EventId` for non-matched rows ( I assusme to last know value). In **`SQL Server 2008`** you don't have access to windowed function `FIRST_VALUE/LAST_VALUE/LAG/LEAD` but you can use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT ii.IntervalHHMM
        , LoggedOnUser
        , dd.EventDate
        , dd.EventTime
        , dd.EventID
FROM (SELECT IntervalHHMM               -- you can use simple #tblIntervalHHMM AS ii 
      FROM #tblIntervalHHMM AS i) AS ii 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
       (SELECT LoggedOnUser
               ,EventDate
               ,CAST(DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, 0, EventTime), 0)
                AS TIME(7)) AS EventTime
               ,EventID
        FROM #tblStaffLoggedInDetails AS sd
        WHERE (LoggedOnUser = 'DWH') 
               AND (EventDate = '2015-10-08')) AS dd 
 ON ii.IntervalHHMM = dd.EventTime
GROUP BY 
  dd.LoggedOnUser,
  dd.EventDate,
  dd.EventTime,
  dd.EventID,
  ii.IntervalHHMM
)
SELECT 
     IntervalHHMM
    ,l.LoggedOnUser
    ,EventDate
    ,EventTime
    ,l2.EventID
FROM cte c
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 LoggedOnUser 
             FROM cte b 
             WHERE b.IntervalHHMM <= c.IntervalHHMM 
              AND b.LoggedOnUser IS NOT NULL 
              ORDER BY IntervalHHMM DESC) AS l
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 EventId
             FROM cte b 
             WHERE b.IntervalHHMM <= c.IntervalHHMM 
              AND b.EventId IS NOT NULL 
              ORDER BY IntervalHHMM DESC) AS l2
ORDER BY IntervalHHMM;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/382945)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════════════╦══════════════╦═════════════════════╦═══════════╦═════════╗
║ IntervalHHMM ║ LoggedOnUser ║      EventDate      ║ EventTime ║ EventID ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════╬═══════════╬═════════╣
║ 07:45:00     ║ DWH          ║ 2015-10-08 00:00:00 ║ 07:45:00  ║    4624 ║
║ 07:46:00     ║ DWH          ║ 2015-10-08 00:00:00 ║ 07:46:00  ║    4800 ║
║ 07:47:00     ║ DWH          ║                     ║           ║    4800 ║
║ 07:48:00     ║ DWH          ║                     ║           ║    4800 ║
║ 07:49:00     ║ DWH          ║                     ║           ║    4800 ║
║ 07:50:00     ║ DWH          ║ 2015-10-08 00:00:00 ║ 07:50:00  ║    4801 ║
║ 07:51:00     ║ DWH          ║                     ║           ║    4801 ║
╚══════════════╩══════════════╩═════════════════════╩═══════════╩═════════╝
```

The cleanest solution I found is to use `LAST_VALUE` but there is one catch. SQL Standard defines `IGNORE NULLS` clause which SQL Server does not support yet.

```
SELECT 
    IntervalHHMM
   ,LAST_VALUE(LoggedOnUser IGNORE NULLS) 
          OVER(ORDER BY IntervalHHMM ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) AS LoggedOnUser
   ,EventDate
   ,EventTime
   ,LAST_VALUE(EventID IGNORE NULLS) 
        OVER(ORDER BY IntervalHHMM ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS EventID
FROM cte c
ORDER BY IntervalHHMM;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo_using_Oracle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0c976/20/0)**</kbd>